# "Unknown subcircuit" error in LTSpiceXVII

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, ltspice

[image]please who can help me to find the solution of this problem

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's just telling you that there's no .SUBCKT (or internal model) for the OPAx227.

This is probably because the text you added (over there on the far right side, that is cut-off so I can't really read it) is showing in a BLUE color, implying that you added it as a COMMENT and not as a SPICE card deck (which shows in a BLACK color, usually.)

To fix it (assuming your .SUBCKT actually specifies the name OPAx227 on it), just right click on the BLUE text on the right and select the "SPICE directive" radio button in the upper LEFT of the dialog box.

When you first see it come up, you should see something like this at the top of the dialog:

[image]

But you want it to read as:

[image]

(Of course, make sure you press the OK button once you change the radio button selection.)

When completed, make sure it now shows up in BLACK color and not BLUE.

If you still have problems, please show the entire schematic so that I can see the complete text of your model.

Comment: the problem is solved thank you very much for your help

Comment: If it worked, then perhaps you should select my answer as "the answer." (You can do that.) I'm not asking for myself (doesn't matter to me.) But it may help save some time of others who pop in to see if they can help out. It's just considerate of others' time, is all. Best wishes and I'm very glad that helped you!

Comment: do you have any idea please how i can do to know if what i did is right or wrong

Comment: @marwa I think you earlier said that "the problem is solved." Is there a new problem, now?

Comment: I do not receive an error but I receive a bode diagram I am not sure that it is correct

Comment: @marwa You should post that up as another question (since it is another question.) This helps to separate things out so that the conversations are more focused and less "meandering and drawn out."

Comment: @marwa  Please see here for more information.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 ||| Please click the gray checkmark to turn it green indicating your "Unknown subcircuit called in..." error has been resolved by this answer.